# Solr 4.0 Delta-import 3 tables join

Tags: mysql, join, solr, dih

I am using Solr 4.0 DIH(JDBC connector) on Ubuntu. I am trying to make the following MySQL JOIN query work with Solr on `Delta-import`:

```
select c.*,u.*,g.* from user u inner join group g on u.bus_grp_id = g.dt_grp_id inner join customer c on c.id = g.dt_id
```

Here c, u, g are the aliases of the tables `customer`, `user` and `group` respectively.

Below is the `data-config.xml` file for full and delta import:

```
<entity name="cust" pk="id" query="select c.*,u.*,g.* from user u inner join group g on u.bus_grp_id = g.dt_grp_id inner join customer c on c.id = g.dt_id"
                deltaImportQuery="select c.*,u.*,g.* from user u inner join group g on u.bus_grp_id = g.dt_grp_id inner join customer c on c.id = g.dt_id where c.id='${dih.delta.c.id}'"
                deltaQuery="select id from customer where last_modified &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'">

                <entity name="grp" pk="dt_id"
                    query="select * from group where dt_id='${cust.c.id}'"
                    deltaQuery="select dt_id from group where last_modified > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
                    parentDeltaQuery="select id from customer where id=${grp.dt_id}" >

                <entity name="usr" pk="bus_grp_id"
                query="select * from user"
                deltaQuery="select bus_grp_id from user where last_modified > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
                parentDeltaQuery="select dt_grp_id from group where dt_grp_id=${usr.bus_grp_id}" >

</entity>
</entity>
</entity>
```

The `full-import` is ok but the `Delta-import` is not working(I'm getting no results after delta import). It's been almost one month since I'm trying to make this work but couldn't.

Any help? please!

Comment: Take a look here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

If the query in your main entity element i.e.

```
select c.*,u.*,g.* from user u 
inner join group g on u.bus_grp_id = g.dt_grp_id 
inner join customer c on c.id = g.dt_id
```

is giving you all the fields you need to index in Solr, I don't think you need the other two sub-entities. Also I guess there is a typo in your deltaImportQuery. You should use `dih.delta.id` and not `dih.delta.c.id`.

I guess if you keep just this, it should work fine:

```
<entity 
   name="cust" 
   pk="id" 
   query="select c.*,u.*,g.* from user u 
            inner join group g on u.bus_grp_id = g.dt_grp_id 
            inner join customer c on c.id = g.dt_id"
   deltaImportQuery="select c.*,u.*,g.* from user u 
            inner join group g on u.bus_grp_id = g.dt_grp_id 
            inner join customer c on c.id = g.dt_id 
              where c.id='${dih.delta.id}'"
   deltaQuery="select id from customer 
                where last_modified &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'" />
```

As soon as you do a full import, check the file dataimport.properties. Once your full import completes, make sure you got some documents in `customer` table with `last_modified` greater than the time you find in dataimport.properties so the delta has some data to run on. Then try delta import and see if those docs get re-indexed. You can find out how many got indexed with the delta import by looking at `http://HOST:PORT/solr/CORE/dataimport`

Comment: Yeah, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to have a single Solr document for every customer in your database? Or do you want to have a single document for every user in your database? (considering the cardinality of your tables customer (1-n) group (1-n) user)

Comment: Yes I want single document for all the 3 tables. I just want the join query to work exactly how it works when queried on database.

Comment: Also, The full-import is not listing the records which are duplicates. I want solr to list everything instead of listing only one record among many duplicate records.

Comment: So you want a separate document for every user (with group and customer info), right? Re duplicates - considering you have id field defined in Solr as uniqueKey you should make SQL clause "select u.id as id, c.*, u.*, g.* ..."

Comment: To speak clearly, I want the join query result with single solr link(only one core). Please could be a bit more specific on duplicates?, could you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: Solr will not allow you to store 2 documents with the same unique key. It can keep only the last document. See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey. BTW, is the delta import working?